# does $a^b \pmod p = (a \pmod p)^b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure whether this is true or not - does $a^b \pmod p = (a \pmod p)^b$?

Searched online but couldn't find a clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you crunch some numbers to verify

Comment: Yes, $(a \mod p) * (a \mod p) = (a^2 \mod p)$ by definition.

Comment: I haven't heard of sth like $(a\mod p)^b$. Can you give some examples?

Comment: One now sees what horrors one encounters if one interprets "$a\mod n$" as an integer.

Comment: If you interpret $a \pmod p$ as an integer, then you should write $a^b \pmod p = (a \pmod p)^b \pmod p$. If you interpret everything as members of GF(p), then the relation becomes $a^b = a^b$

Comment: @Damien shouldn't it be , $\equiv$ ?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- For the first or second relation ? For the first equation, it seems to be a question of convention. In college, I was told to use your notation. Then, the second... But it was decades ago, and in France

Comment: @Damien, what is GF(p)? great (common) factor?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Galois Field $Z/pZ$

Comment: @Damien, out of my knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Probably the main reason you can't find a clear answer is because the notation is a bit confusing. When you work with the integers "modulo $p$", you aren't working with *integers* any more, but rather *equivalence classes* of integers.
Writing $5\pmod3=2$ is an abuse of notation, as what you're really saying is
$$
5 \equiv 2 \pmod 3
$$
that is, "$5$ and $2$ are in the same equivalence class modulo $3$." In other words, $5-2$ is a multiple of $3$ (this is all that "$\pmod3$" really says). It's generally dangerous to think of "$\pmod3$" as a function into the integers because things like $(a\pmod p)^b$ aren't so clear. For example, should I think of $(5\pmod3)^5$ as $2^5=32$? If I do then the answer to your question is "no" but this is likely not what you had in mind.

From the perspective of equivalence classes, the question becomes more straightforward: is the mapping $a\mapsto a^b$ well defined modulo $p$? That is, if $a\equiv a'\pmod p$, then is $a^b\equiv(a')^b\pmod p$ also? This is likely the question you meant to ask, and the answer to this question is yes! This means that computing $a^b\pmod p$ can be done by first computing $a^b$ and then looking at its equivalence class modulo $p$, and also by taking $a$'s equivalence class modulo $p$ and then working with multiplication in this world.

The reason why this is true is because multiplication is well-defined modulo $p$: if $a\equiv a'\pmod p$ and $b\equiv b'\pmod p$, then $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod p$. To see this, we can just use the definition: we need to show that $ab-a'b'$ is a multiple of $p$, which follows because
$$
ab-a'b' = ab - ab' + ab' - a'b' = a(b-b') + (a-a')b'
$$
Since $a-a'$ and $b-b'$ are multiples of $p$ by assumption, the right hand side is a multiple of $p$ and therefore $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod p$, as desired.

A word of warning however, negative exponents can make sense modulo $p$ too, despite this not making sense over the integers. The inverse $a^{-1}$ is supposed to be a number that, when multiplied by $a$, gives you $1$. In the context of the integers, $5^{-1}=\frac15$ satisfies this, but is definitely not an integer. However, if we look at equivalence classes modulo $3$, we can actually find some $a$ such that $5a\equiv1\pmod3$. Indeed, here we can take $a=2$, then $5a\equiv10\equiv1\pmod3$, and we usually write this as
$$
5^{-1}\equiv2\pmod3
$$
and this is certainly not something you could have computed by taking $5^{-1}$ first in the world of integers (er, rationals) and then finding an equivalence class modulo $3$.